# Create semi-transparent panel with C++ and WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, background, panel, opacity

I have a window with a background image and I want to create a panel (like in .NET) with a white border and a semi-transparent background *RGBA(255, 255, 255, 124)*, so the image in the background could be also visible. Should I use *STATIC* control or a child window for that? I know that in order to set the *RGBA* color of a window I have to use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, but I don't know if that would work with *STATIC* control.

What type of control is used normally for this and what **WINAPI** functions could I use to set the border thickness and color?
Thanks

**SOME CODE:**

```
// Create the static control (inside the WM_CREATE of the parent window)
hPanel = CreateWindowEx(
    WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, 
    L"STATIC", 
    L"", 
    WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_WHITEFRAME, 
    10, 90, 
    200, 120, 
    hWnd, 
    (HMENU)IDC_PANEL, 
    hInstance, 
    NULL);

// Trying to set the alpha level
SetWindowLong(hPanel , GWL_EXSTYLE, 
    GetWindowLong(hPanel , GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_LAYERED);
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hPanel , 0, (255 * 70) / 100, LWA_ALPHA);

// Changing the background color of the STATIC in WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    hStatic = (HDC)wParam;
    switch (GetDlgCtrlID((HWND)lParam)) {
        case IDC_PANEL:
            SetTextColor(hStatic, RGB(255, 255, 255));
            SetBkColor(hStatic, RGB(26, 127, 231));
        break;
        default:
            SetTextColor(hStatic, RGB(255, 255, 255));    
            SetBkMode (hStatic, TRANSPARENT);
    }
    return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    break;
```

So, the only thing I get with this code is a transparent bordered control. I don't get the background color and the alpha effect.

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Static controls like all custom and common controls _are_ child windows.

Comment: I added some code of what I have tried

Comment: WS_EX_LAYERED isn't supported on child windows until Windows 8.